# Images are broken in HTML?

Tags: html

I am currently doing an HTML class for my career field, first time doing it and I ran into an error. I have my other web pages all set in the individual folders but this one is a pain to get running. I will provide the directory and the code. 
directory:

> /shares/College Students/(my username)/public_html/comw100/webpage3/webpage4/images/

(the image folder is my images)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Program Courses</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <img src="/images/mcc_top_logo.png" />
        <img src="/images/table.png" />
        <img src="/images/mcc_bottom_logo.png" />
    </body>
</html>
```

And this webpage gives me the html error saying this  file is not found even though it is under webpage4 folder.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title> My Portfolio</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body bgcolor="mccfcc">
<h1>My Portfolio</h1>
<h3>(my name)</h3>
<hr/>
<h1>Web Page Activities</h1> 
<ul>
    <li>Web page 1: Home Page</li>
    <li>Web page 2: Portfolio</li>
    <li><a href="webpage3/index.html">Web page 3: Web Tutorial</a></li>
    <li><a href="webpage4/index.html">Web page 4: Personal Courses</a></li>
    <li>Web page 5: HTML Forms</li>
    <li>Web page 6: External Media and Apps</li>
    <li>Web page 7: Text formatting with CSS</li>
    <li>Web page 8: More CSS Formatting</li>
    <li>Web Page 9: Responsive design with boot strap</li>
    <li>Web page 10: Transitions and Transforms</li>
    <li>Web Page 11: Java</li>
    <li>Web Page 12: Templates</li>
</ul>
<h1>Projects</h1>
<ul>
    <li>Project 1: Display of Skills</li>
    <li>Project 2: Display of Skills</li>
    <li>Final Project</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you bring up the image alone in a browser? Checked the permissions on the images folder and the images themselves?

Comment: I can open the images up without a problem into Google Chrome

Comment: What's one of the URLs?

Comment: file:///C:/Users/Dylan/Downloads/mcc_top_logo.png

Comment: That's the file path to the image on your local machine. You need the URL on the server. Something like `http://<your college domain>/(my username)/public_html/comw100/webpage3/webpage4/images/mcc_top_logo.png` or `http://<your collage domain>/(my username)/comw100/webpage3/webpage4/images/mcc_top_logo.png`

Comment: I'm assuming he is running this locally and not on a server. He is doing this for a class.

Comment: That is what I am trying to do, I am trying to run it on a server for my class.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of achieving that:

Either start the URL with `./` like:

```
<img src="./images/mcc_top_logo.png" />
```

or without that as:

```
<img src="images/mcc_top_logo.png" />
```

Comment: Muhammad, I did both ways, but the images are still broken, so it might be a directory issue. But if not, I am at a loss.

Comment: compare the dir where the html file and where the images are.  then use either a absolute path from the root of your server or a relative path from where the html file is being served from

Comment: It’s hard to sort this without the correct information. Open in Chrome, right click broken images and open in new tab and post the url in here. I think your images are in the wrong place looking at your initial image folder. Why is there webpage3/webpage4/images/???

Answer (score 0):

Using [this](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp) as a reference for you:

If the directory of your current html file is webpage4 then

```
<img src="images/myImage.png" />
```

if the directory of your current html file is webpage3 then

```
<img src="webpage4/images/myImage.png" />
```

if the directory of the html file is comw100 then

```
<img src="webpage3/webpage4/images/myImage.png" />
```

etc.

You provided your full path, but the path you care about is the path of the directory that you are currently in, which is referenced from the HTML page you have open.

Comment: Like what I said to Muhammad, still getting the broken images.

Comment: Where is your html file? Because the html posted isn't wrong, which means either you have implemented the code wrong somehow or you have a separate issue going on that isn't the code itself.

Comment: My html file is located in the webpage4 folder, the next folder is the image folder

Comment: Can you verify the file extension of your images to make sure you are referencing them correctly (e.g. png or jpg)? Your src should be "images/myImage.png"

Comment: Thats what I have, still a broken image

Comment: I've just verified the logic I posted locally to make sure that I am not crazy. You either have a misspelling, the wrong file extension, a broken image, or somehow did not use the code correctly.

Comment: Based on your comment, your file is not in the correct area. If it is in your Downloads folder then you must copy it/cut it from that folder and paste it into your images folder.